# spawn_id: spawn id exp6 not open

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, expect

I know that this issue is already mentioned here, but the solution does not work for me.

I have this script (let's name it myscript.sh) that spawns a process on remote environment and that should interact with it.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
log_user 0
set timeout 10
spawn ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no [lindex $argv 0] -n [lindex $argv 1]
expect "password:" {send "mypassword\r"}
expect "Continue to run (y/n)" {send "n\r"}
interact
```

When I call this script on local environment...

```
myscript.sh user@host "command1;./command2 parameter1 parameter2"
```

I get the above error at line 7 (interact)

Any ideas??

Comment: You're passing the remote command as an argument to ssh, so that ssh session will end when the remote command completes. There will be nothing to interact with.

Comment: Yes, but that remote command should not end before it gets an input on "Continue to run (y/n)". After passing "y\r" it should run for about another 2 minutes... Shouldn't interact command forward the remote command's output to my stdout until the end of execution?

Comment: Are you *sure* you're getting to the [interact] in good shape, and not just timing-out?  Do you know how to debug Expect dialogues?

Comment: I don't think I'm timing out, as timeout is set to 10 seconds, and I get the error message almost insantly. No, I don't know how to debug it (at least I'm not aware of any "official" tool, or method for doing so) :(

Comment: 1.  Start with http://wiki.tcl.tk/3173; 2.  be sure you've resolved Glenn's observation.  More details, later in the day.

Comment: exp_internal 1 ;# you'll be able to see what is coming from the spawned process. Also having log_user 0 while trying to debug is... counterproductive.

Comment: Cameron Laird thank you a lot... I managed to resolve my issues after reading this article you gave us link to. Also thx to Duane for pointing out the fact that log_user 0 is not helpful when debugging :D. Vote up for both of you.

Comment: I ran into this error when I was trying to use `plink` with a USB device. It turns out that my account did not have appropriate permissions to access USB devices, so the process was never spawned and the expect failed automagically. After setting the appropriate permissions everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect the expect is not able to find out(matching) the pattern you are sending.

```
expect "password:" {send "mypassword\r"}
expect "Continue to run (y/n)" {send "n\r"}
```

Check out again whether the "password:" and "Continue to run (y/n)" are in correct CAPS.

If still getting the same error, you can try using regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script to handle different expectations, whether there was a "yes/no" or "password" or `eof` in case of no match.

```bash
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn ssh-copy-id -i $dest_user@$ip
expect {
  "yes/no" { 
    send "yes\r";exp_continue 
  } "password" { 
    send "$passwd\r" 
  } eof { 
    exit
  }
}
expect of
```

EOF

Comment: It would be a good idea to add at least a brief explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a normal ssh without script. See if it works. Sometimes the remote host identification changes, and the host has a new ip or new key. Then it helps to remove the old key with `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R old_host`, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was down to using the wrong port.

Comment: Plese, consider a to comment or provide a better answer. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -2):

I ran into this issue as well but it was due to me creating/editing the following file for an unrelated item:

```
~/.ssh/config
```

Once I deleted that, all my scripts began working and I no longer got that issue with my expect file.

Comment: For future readers that might see this answer: please do not delete `~/.ssh/config`, it will not magically fix the error.